# DrawPrimitives performance

Tags: performance, xna

I want to draw single faces instead of xna models because it's too slow.

But I don't know what the difference is between

- DrawPrimitives
- DrawUserPrimitives
- DrawIndexedPrimitives
- DrawUserIndexedPrimitives

Which one is the fastest method? And what are the indices good for?

Comment: In most cases the xna drawing method is pretty fast. If it is too slow, then maybe your model is too big or the graphics card is too slow. Without any evidence, I would assume that the DrawIndexedPrimitives is the fastest method. Indices allow vertices to be reused. So they have to be computed only once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is that the "`User`" versions are a fair bit slower **on the CPU** because they have to transfer vertex data to the GPU (via the driver and the bus) each time they are called.

The non-`User` versions use vertex and index buffers that already exist on the GPU (you put them there at load time). They have considerably less data to transfer, so they are faster.

The "`User`" and "`Indexed`" versions will also each have a performance impact on the **GPU**. This impact is relatively tiny. Generally speaking you don't need to worry about it.

The `User` versions exist because they are faster when your data changes each frame. There is also `DynamicVertexBuffer` which can be used with the non-`User` version of the draw functions. I believe it is slightly faster than the `User` methods in cases where you can pre-allocate the buffer at the desired size.

The `Indexed` versions allow you to select vertices out of your vertex buffer using an index buffer (so triangles that you draw can choose vertices at any position in the vertex buffer). The alternative is that your vertex buffer is simply interpreted as as sequential list of triangle vertices (based on `PrimitiveType`). The main reason for the existence of index buffers is to remove the need for duplicate vertices in your vertex buffer (which would require additional memory and processing on the GPU).

**BUT...**

XNA's `Model` class internally uses `DrawIndexedPrimitives`. Not only that, but it uses it *correctly* (ie: it doesn't draw single faces - but as many as it can at once - for the best performance). So if you are finding that it is slow, then your problem lies elsewhere.

I suggest trying to diagnose the *reason* why your game is performing poorly, before trying to select a "solution". Maybe ask for help doing that in a question here (or on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: thank you!
Isn't it faster when I draw the (all the) models vertices together at one time instead of drawing hundreds of models?

Comment: @ThinkingThunder If you can merge all of the models into a single vertex buffer, then yes that will be faster. However then you won't be able to move the models around independently (which is the purpose of `Model`). Alternately you could look into **instancing**, which would let you draw multiple copies of the same model very quickly.

Comment: I would like to change the vertex buffer every few seconds, so would it still be faster?
I can't use instancing because I'm programming for windows phone.
Thanks again :)

Comment: @ThinkingThunder Probably best if you ask in a new question. You're getting into territory I can't be 100% sure about my answers - particularly on the Windows Phone hardware. If it were me, I'd go with the easiest thing - which is probably a dynamic vertex buffer to `DrawIndexedPrimitives`. That is easy and should be sufficiently fast. It may be faster to use a pair of non-dynamic vertex buffers in a double-buffer arrangement - fill one in a background thread, and then swap it with the one being drawn. But that is *a lot harder* and probably not worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

All in one time if you can , Instancied draw will be always better , but that need you to give all the textures in one time ! In my case , for example , I like to draw instancied objects with 1 only texture ... all the trees , all the ground , all buildings , etc ...